# See all revisions that changed a specific file

Tags: svn

On **svn**, how can I list all revisions that changed a specific file (or a list of files)? It can recieve an interval if necessary, and search within that, or work on every revision ever made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you could just `svn log <filename>`... Derp! **svn** is so confusing to me sometimes this just didn't make it to my mind.